# How to change font size on blog pages created on Github using JekyllNow

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I created a Github.io blog using JekyllNow. JekyllNow allows you to create it fully on the web itself without having git or Ruby installed locally. i.e. everything was done without any local operation.

I am using the minimal theme. My page is created but the font seems very big. How do I change the font sizes on the page?

If there is a way to make it proportional, that would be even better - i.e. i.e. not just the default font size but also, H1, H2 etc sizes also are proportionally smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally we edit the file [`style.scss`](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now/blob/v1.2.0/_sass/_variables.scss) located at the root of the jekyll instance.

```
 body {
      font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

But, if you are using the default Jekyll theme "*Minima*", you will have to edit the file `minima.scss` instead of the `style.scss`.

So, To change the default font size definition you need to reset the value of `$base-font-size'

```
$base-font-size:   16px !default;
```

Also you can change the default font definition itself by resetting the value of `$base-font-family` variable,

```
$base-font-family: "PT Serif", serif;
```

You will also need to remove the `!default;` suffix at the end of this setting for the new font to be applicable.

Comment: `$base-font-size:   16px !default;` - once you change this what happens to H1, H2 etc? Do they change proportionally or do they still remain as they were before?

Comment: should be adjusted accordingly, i have used the `$base-font-family:` and it changes the heaidngs, didn't try the `$base-font-size` though